# JPA Problems: Unable to build entity manager factory

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

JPA doesn't work for me no matter what I do.
I followed a course on udemy exactly, tried to import the actual project (changing mysql user/pw), tried other tutorials on youtube. Nothing works.

The following is the imported source from the course. The Pom and the persistence look pretty much like the majority on the internet. The Main App itself is later in the course, because I can't find the old source. But even the most basic code doesn't work.

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.udemy</groupId>
<artifactId>FirstJPAProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="personal_jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/udemy?serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="Password123" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Main Class:

```
package com.udemy.jpa;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("personal_jpa");

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        TypedQuery<Person> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("person.getPersonByName", Person.class);
        query.setParameter("name", "Adam");

        List<Person> people = query.getResultList();

        for (Person p : people) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }

        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();

    }
}
```

And I keep getting this (or similar) errors all the time:

```
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:34 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:34 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:34 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:34 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: personal_jpa
    ...]
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:34 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:35 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/udemy?serverTimezone=UTC]
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 25, 2018 7:40:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Sun Nov 25 19:40:35 CET 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.udemy.inheritance.App.main(App.java:10)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:695)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:638)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:624)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:620)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:77)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1683)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:656)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:349)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.authentication.MysqlaAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlaAuthenticationProvider.java:550)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.authentication.MysqlaAuthenticationProvider.connect(MysqlaAuthenticationProvider.java:196)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.connect(MysqlaProtocol.java:1712)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:149)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1803)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1673)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: What happens if you use the non-deprecated provider, as the logs suggest? `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`

Comment: if I replace it by:
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
in the persistence.xml

Nothing changes. I get the same error

Comment: OK I got rid of the first warns by using:
PersistenceProvider provider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = provider.createEntityManagerFactory("personal_jpa", properties);

I think the problem is:
Unable to build entity manager factory

Comment: Well, the root of the problem seems to be coming from the MySQL connector: "WrongArgumentException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'". Make sure everything is configured correctly, including on the MySQL side. You do appear to be using an older version of `mysql-connector-java`. What happens if you try a [more recent version](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:mysql%20AND%20a:mysql-connector-java)?

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot. It works now.
The course is quite out dated

Answer (score 1):

> Slaw:
>   Well, the root of the problem seems to be coming from the MySQL
>   connector: "WrongArgumentException: Unable to load authentication
>   plugin 'caching_sha2_password'". Make sure everything is configured
>   correctly, including on the MySQL side. You do appear to be using an
>   older version of mysql-connector-java. What happens if you try a more
>   recent version?

It works now. Had to try an other version.